# Is it possible to include NA for one missing value, and can I verify that each individual corresponds with my specified function

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have code here that generates a random spatial distribution of points, returns a distance column between every point and an infected individual and uses a function to calculate the probability of infection in the next time step. There are 60 hosts, one of which is infected. I would like to bind the values of Pi (which calculates infection probability) to my data frame with the original co-ordinates. Obviously one point is removed from the distance matrix, the infected individual. This value I would like to replace with NA in the main data frame as the next step in my code, and also to confirm that the co-ordinates correspond with the output of the function Pi.

*So as it stands I am trying to attach a column of 59 rows to the main data frame of 60 rows.*

```
# Create a spatial distribution with infected individuals

xcoord <- sample(1:100,60)
ycoord <- sample(1:100,60)
infectionstatus <- rep(0,60)
Df <- data.frame(xcoord, ycoord, infectionstatus)

a <- sample(1:60, 1)
Df$infectionstatus[a] <- 1

# Calculate distance between infected individuals and susceptibles

library(rdist)

distances <- pdist(Df[,1:2], metric = "euclidean")
position_infected_individual <- which(Df[,3]==1)
distance_from_infected <- distances[-(position_infected_individual), position_infected_individual]

#Assign parameter values and calculate probability of infection

beta<-100
alpha<-0.1
Pi<-vector()
for (p in 1:length(distance_from_infected)){
  Pi[p] = 1-exp(-beta*exp(-alpha*distance_from_infected[p]))
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the title have anything to do with a problem you are trying to solve? Practically, it makes no sense to say the "distance" from an infected person to their self is missing. It's 0. I'm sure the distance function should confirm that. But they are removed from the risk set. The point is that you need to create a subset of at-risk individuals within each time point for which the distance matrix (vector actually) is 1-1. We do similar things in Cox models of time-to-event outcomes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. My question is how do I add a NA value to the Pi vector just to the location where the infected individual is. I see, I have not heard of Cox models of time-to-event outcomes, sounds interesting, do you mean 1-1 between the probability of infection to the co-ordinates of the at risk individuals? That is what I am trying to do, however, perhaps I should think more about the distance vector, thank you for correcting me I am relatively new to R. Hope that helped!

Comment: Why do you remove the `position_infected_individual` from distances?

Comment: I remove the `position_infected_individual` because a. I do not want to include a distance to itself and b. that individual is already infected and hence is not included in my equation which states the likelihood that an individual will become infected.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious step is:

replace:
`distance_from_infected <- distances[-(position_infected_individual), position_infected_individual]`

with:

`distance_from_infected <- c(NA, distances[-(position_infected_individual), position_infected_individual])`

But you're setting yourself up for quite a few failures.

1. Assuming only one infected case
2. That the DF can always be appropriately sorted so infected individual is first
3. That `NA` makes "sense" for this kind of numeric summary